# Docker-compose should run a service only once

Tags: postgresql, npm, docker-compose

I have a script that creates tables on a postgresql and inserts a couple rows. This script is a `npm run` script which executes `sequelize.init()` and a couple more js lines. I need this script to run only the first time I start my app.

This is my current `docker-compose.yml`

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: "3.7"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: app
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: app
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - app-db:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  app-be:
    build:
      context: ./backend
    env_file:
     - ./backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  app-be-init:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-Init
    env_file:
     - ./backend/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres

  app-fe:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
    env_file:
     - ./frontend/.env
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
        
volumes:
  app-db:
```

Is there a way to configure this on `docker-compose`, or should `app-be-init` be aware enough to not trigger if it has already created tables?

Comment: Why not add an `IF NOT EXIST` to your `CREATE` and subsequent `INSERT` query in your script?

Comment: Yes that might be the simplest approach

Comment: should i phrase the comment as an answer?

Comment: It is a workaround. I think the real question behind this is: should migration/init scripts run always on startup and decide themselves to execute or not, or should they only be executed when required (and have a higher hierarchy process handle this logic) ?

Comment: Why not set a 'flag' if the script executed? (could be a simple .json file in the app root with a property 'executed':boolean written on end of the execution by the script itself). In the beginning of the script you may check the value of that file and fork your logic for executing stuff

Comment: feel free to post any of your solutions as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A really simple approach/workaround (as of postrgesql 9.1 where it was intriduced) would be to add a `IF NOT EXISTS` clause to your `CREATE TABLE` statement and your subsequent 'INSERT' could check via `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Some more info from can be found here in the [official docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtable.html).

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE foo IF NOT EXIST;
INSERT INTO foo (ID, COL1, COL2)
    SELECT 1, 'barfoo', 'foobar', 
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM foo WHERE id='1')
```

Since you mentioned in your comments that you rather solve this porogrammatically instead with a workaround you could set a 'flag' if the script successfully executed (might want to check for exitcodes..).

It could be a simple .json file in the app root with a property `{'executed':true/false}` written on end of the execution by the script itself.

In the beginning of the script you may check the value of that file and fork your logic for executing stuff.